# Understanding JQuery Selector

Tags: jquery

Hi,

What's difference between:

```
  $('li:first').css('background-color', 'red');
```

And

```
  $('li').first().css('background-color', 'red');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They will both perform the same action.

The second one will gather all `<li>` tags into a jQuery object, then retrieve the first one in a separate jQuery object.
If you have many `<li>` tags, that may be slow.

On the other hand, the first one will not be able to use `querySelectorAll()` (since there is no `:first` CSS selector), so it may be slower too.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is what is being brought back in the first call to operate on.

`$('li:first')` Will either bring back the first item or nothing (if none are found).

`$('li').first()` Will bring back all **`<li>`** items and then select the first item in the list for you to continue operating on.

Performance wise they likely both have the same impact so it's a matter of preference and style.

Answer (score 1):

li:first is like direct selector by jquery
li.first(). - you are selecting child elements using jquery method.